# x86 why do i keep getting CD in the al register when moving a variable

Tags: x86, dos, x86-16, emu8086, real-mode

Titles say the question. But basically every time I use the MOV instruction with a variable to a register the register display CD. but when I use an actual number the register display the number?

[image]

Does mov ax, @data mean move the data segment memory address to the ax register and does it have to be exclusively the ax register. Or could I do something like move mov bx, @data if I wanted to work with the variable in the bx register.  Please answer

Why do I have to do mov ds, ax what does ds do why am confused someone help meh.

Comment: Your code isn't setting the DS register so your memory accesses are coming from the wrong place. At the start of your code you need to do something like `mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax` to setup DS. The reason you keep seeing CD is that at offset 0 of the Program Segment Prefix there is an `int 20h` instruction to terminate the program. The `int 20h` instruction is encoded as 0CDh, 020h.

Comment: I forgot to mention that before you set DS to the @data segment, the default DS points to the DOS [Program Segment Prefix](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~xyfeng/research/cos/resources/BIOS/Resources/assembly/programsegmentprefix.html).

Comment: Am trying to learn X86 what does the instruction mov ax, @data mean and do and mov ds, ax do in English please. Am new to this am a C# developer trying to learn X86 thank you for replying.

Comment: So can I assume the mov @data is moving everything from the data segment into memory or something or it tells the computer where my vars are. It's like I find this so frustrating because as a programmer I want to know why something is there I don't want to simply memorise something and not know why it's there

Comment: It is more complex than that and beyond the scope of explaining in a comment. You need to understand real mode segment offset addressing. You probably need to find a tutorial on using EMU8086.

Comment: I'm not sure real mode code and emu8086 would be a good use of time when learning reverse engineering in the modern era given that emu8086 emulates 16-bit DOS and most OSes and code running in them are running in 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

Comment: Does mov ax, a data mean move the data segment memory address to the ax register and does it have to be exclusively the ax register. Or could I do something like move mov bx, @data if I wanted to work with the variable in the bx register. Please answer

Why do I have to do mov ds, ax what does ds do why am confused someone help meh. But everyone says X86 is important if you want to learn reverse engineering?? Your confusing me plZzz help me am running out of memory in my brain. Don't go plz help. Meh

Comment: Modern x86 code (32 and 64-bit mode) use a flat memory model, with all segment base addresses set to `0` (except for FS or GS for thread-local storage, but their base address is normally set by a different mechanism).  **For modern reverse-engineering, 16-bit segmented memory models are a complete waste of your time** (and of memory in your brain), especially real-mode where segment registers have a different meaning that protected mode or long mode.  Sep's answer is good if you want to still mess around with 16-bit DOS code at all, instead of 32 or 64-bit code that uses normal Windows calls.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're using the `.model small` directive, the assembler creates an .EXE type program. You need a better understanding about real mode segmented addressing to work from an .EXE.

Luckily there's another program format that is much simpler. The .COM type programs start with all of the segment register equal to each other. `CS`=`DS`=`ES`=`SS`. You can work easily from offsets only. This is the best choice you can make to learn assembly.

Example:

```
ORG 256          ;              This asks for a .COM program

mov  bl, var1    ;              Very first instruction in the program
mov  ax, var2

mov  ax, 4C00h   ; DOS.TerminateProgram
int  21h

var1  db 4       ; Byte         Place all the data below the code!
var2  dw 1000    ; Word
```

There's nothing more to it.